# crop and center a square formed by points with OpenCV python

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

estaba queriendo hacer un corte de un cuadrado formado por puntos y luego centrar ese corte en una imagen con opencv en python, tengo un problema al generar un cuadrado alrededor del lugar donde tengo más puntos.
Esta es la imagen original:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto es lo que obtengo cuando quiero encerrar la parte con la mayor cantidad de puntos dentro de un rectángulo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El rectángulo queda así porque hay píxeles dispersos.
Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('123456__.png')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,64,255,0)

kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
img_e = cv2.dilate(thresh,kernel,iterations = 1)
imgbw, contours, hierarchy = 
cv2.findContours(img_e,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
margin_distance = 25
def get_min_max_values(cs, im_y, im_x):
 min_y = im_y - margin_distance
 min_x = im_x - margin_distance
 max_y = margin_distance
 max_x = margin_distance
 for lvl1 in cs:
     for lvl2 in lvl1:
         x, y = lvl2[0]
         # x = im_x - x
         # y = im_y - y
         max_y = max(y, max_y) if y + margin_distance < im_y else max_y
         max_x = max(x, max_x) if x + margin_distance < im_x else max_x
         min_y = min(y, min_y) if y > margin_distance else min_y
         min_x = min(x, min_x) if x > margin_distance else min_x
  return ((min_y, min_x), (min_y, max_x), (max_y, min_x), (max_y, max_x))

  new_rect = get_min_max_values(contours, len(img), len(img[0]))
  new_rect = list(map(lambda x: list(x)[::-1], list(new_rect)))
  rect = cv2.minAreaRect(np.int0(new_rect))
  box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
  box = np.int0(box)

  img_out = cv2.drawContours(img, [box], -1, (0,0,255), 5) # -1 = wszystkie kontury
  img_out = cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

  cv2.imwrite("outssss.png",
```

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda!

Comment: Saludos estas en **SO en Español**, así que traduce tu pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que, al menos para el ejemplo que planteas, es mucho más simple aumentar la dilatación para rellenar por completo los huecos y luego quedarse con el contorno de mayor área. Esto lo puedes hacer simplemente aumentando el tamaño del kernel en función de la dispersión esperada de los "puntos" de tu rectángulo:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2



def crop_min_rect(img, countour):
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(countour)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int0(box)

    w, h = (int(n) for n in  rect[1])
    xs, ys = zip(*box)
    x1, y1 = min(xs), min(ys)
    x2, y2 = max(xs), max(ys)
    center = int((x1 + x2) / 2), int((y1 + y2) / 2)
    size = int((x2 - x1)), int((y2 - y1))

    rotated = False
    angle = rect[2]

    if angle < -45:
        angle += 90
        rotated = True

    rot_m = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((size[0] / 2, size[1] / 2), angle, 1.0)
    cropped = cv2.warpAffine(cv2.getRectSubPix(img, size, center), rot_m, size)

    cw = w if not rotated else h
    ch = h if not rotated else w

    img_crop = cv2.getRectSubPix(cropped, (cw, ch), (size[0] / 2, size[1] / 2))
    im_draw  = cv2.drawContours(img, [box], -1, (0, 0, 255), 5)
    return im_draw, img_crop



KERNEL_SIZE = 20

img = cv2.imread('123456__.png')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 64, 255, 0)

kernel = np.ones((KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE), np.uint8)
img_e = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img_e, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

max_countour = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)

cont_img, crop_img = crop_min_rect(img, max_countour)

cv2.imwrite("countour.png", cont_img)
cv2.imwrite("cropped.png", crop_img)
```

### countour.png

[image: countour.png]

### cropped.png

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]